# "(#200) Provide valid app ID", when accessing graph API explorer via URL

Tags: json, api, url, facebook-graph-api, error-handling

I want to retrieve data regarding insights of my Facebook posts. I am able to retrieve all this information under graph API explorer but keep on getting errors the moment I put it into a graph URL.
Here is the URL :

`https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{page_id}/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_engaged_users,page_posts_impressions_unique)&token_access=ACCESS_TOKEN`

(I removed the page_id and ACCESS_TOKEN for privacy.)

I end up getting this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Provide valid app ID",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200,
      "fbtrace_id": "AuaCwwoNGZW_U4Ivay4Xi1f"
   }
}
```

Can someone guide me on what to do in this case? I guess I have to include my app_ID into the Graph API URL, but where exactly?

Thank you.

I searched for a solution from the Facebook developer community but could not get any solutions.

Comment: Did you try switching your App Mode from "Development" mode to "Live"? I wonder if that's a necessary step.

Comment: Yes I did , the problem was that instead of using me under page_id , I used the page ID itself . The issue was fixed by  replacing the page_id by me.